# What are the number of output bits of the internal function F used in BPS algorithm?

Tags: format-preserving

In the BPS specification [document](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/bps/bps-spec.pdf) it says

> We denote by f the number of output bits of the internal function F

What is this if the internal function is AES? Would it be the block size (e.g. 128)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in BPS, if the internal function $F$ is a block cipher, then $f$ is its block width, thus 128 for AES (for all key width variants). That's clear enough in the [paragraph](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/bps/bps-spec.pdf#page=3) quoted in the question:

> We denote by $f$ the number of output bits of the internal function $F$. <sub><sup>(...)</sup></sub>
>   If $F$ is a $f$-bit block cipher <sub><sup>(...)</sup></sub>
>   We denote by $F_K(x)$ the application of the block cipher $E$ with the key $K$ on the plaintext $x$ ($F_K(x)=E_K(x)$), <sub><sup>(...)</sup></sub>